# pagination on post listing through display post shortcode wordpress plugin

Tags: pagination, wordpress

i'm working on wordpress with the bootstrap theme. i have displayed the post listing through display post shortcode with some modification as post thumbnail, title,and date with span3.so i'm displaying 12 post in 3 rows.now i want to show next 12 posts in next page with pagination.how can i avhive it?

Here is my output of display post shortcode:

```
$output = '<' . $inner_wrapper . ' class="' . implode( ' ', $class ) . '">' . $image . $title .'<br/>'. $newspaper.'<br/>'. $news_date->format('d-m-Y') . $excerpt . $content . '</' . $inner_wrapper . '>';
```

and here is how i call the shortcode in my template:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[display-posts category="news-room-news" image_size="thumbnail" posts_per_page="12" orderby="date"]'); ?>
```

Comment: if you are using display-posts-shortcode plugin then it's not possible because plugin doesn't support pagination.

Comment: @RamSharma: yes i'm using that plugin...:( is there any way to achieve it with display post shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `offset` parameter.
If you wish to display a limited no. of posts per page, say like 5 and the same value on every page, then do like below:

```
[display-posts include_excerpt="true" category="abc" image_size="thumbnail" wrapper="div" posts_per_page="5" include_date="true" date_format="F j, Y"] 
<!--nextpage-->
[display-posts include_excerpt="true" category="abc" image_size="thumbnail" wrapper="div" posts_per_page="5" include_date="true" date_format="F j, Y" offset="5"] <!--previouspage-->
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the plugin does not support pagination. Pagination should be done either with the main WordPress queries or by building a custom query in a page template.